# Why is WebKit not redrawing this text properly?

Tags: html, css, webkit

I've got a pretty specific issue with the WebKit renderer. When a text node has a descender or ascender that extends beyond the selection box of the text node, and that text node changes position, WebKit doesn't repaint the right region.

[I've made an example with Open Sans.](http://jsfiddle.net/p4Ezr/8/)

In Chrome on Windows 7, the descender on the `J` gets cut off during the animation. I can fix it by adding a margin to the text node, but that's a bit of a hack and it screws with layout. Does anyone see this in other browsers? Why is it happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug in Webkit. You need to let Webkit know that there's painted pixels beyond its bounding box, which you can do in a couple of ways, but here are two that I've found with some quick testing:

```
#expand {
    height: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

#expand {
    height: 0px;
    outline: solid transparent 5px;
}
```

I'm guessing `outline` has better performance.

It seems to work if you add it `#expand` or `p` as well. There's some flags in Chrome which you can enable to see how redraw regions work, but I don't have them handy right now.

Comment: The outline solution is a good idea. It doesn't affect the layout like padding or margin, but still forces the redraw region to grow. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

I threw a `padding-left: 5px;` on the `#container p` rule, the J was outside the box.

Hope that helps.

*edit
I miss read, not sure if the padding thing would also mess with your layout, I assume so.

Comment: Yea, I found the padding and margin fix and that will work for most cases. I'm more curious about why this is happening and if there is a generic solution to it.

Comment: @atonparker After looking at it, I see that the `#container` has a width of 100% and then you put a padding on it, that actually make the container larger than 100%. The [Box Model](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/) takes the width + padding-left + padding-right + border-left + border-right. Could be something to consider as a possible cause.

Comment: I changed the container to have a fixed width. The padding is just so the descender of the J is visible. I think the root issue is the descender extends beyond the computed width of the text node (try selecting the text to see it). I'm looking for a solution to make WebKit repaint the entire container.